# Matlab Simscape pressurizing and depressurizing a vessel

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I am trying to do a very simple simulation in Simscape but I have the feeling I still don't fully grasp the conservative ports and physical signals.

I have a very simple pneumatic model:
A vessel of volume V, an air pump, a tube and a solenoid valve.

This is the electric equivalent circuit:
[image: Electrical equivalent system (open)]

The tube is a resitance, the vessel a capacitor and the solenoid a simple switch. The pump is modelled as a constant current source.

In Simulink Simscape I have modeled it as a pneumatic model like this:
[image: Pneumatic model]

**Except** for the solenoid, because I have no idea how. In my electrical equivalent I short it to ground when the solenoid is switched:

[image: Electrical equivalent system (closed)]

and the system should release to the atmosphere.

I tried to model the solenoid by creating a switch using PS Switch and trying to switch the resistive tube A from the flow rate source to the atmosphere, but it does not allow a connection, probably because the signal types are of incorrect types.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this? Should I make my own component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create your own component. Have a look at the [Pneumatic Actuation Circuit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/simscape/examples/pneumatic-actuation-circuit.html) or the [Pneumatic Motor and Directional Control Valve](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/simscape/examples/pneumatic-motor-and-directional-control-valve.html) examples for examples of how to create valve models using Foundation Library blocks.